# Drop Down CSS is not working

Tags: html, css

This is my code [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/jhvmuwjs/)

```
Label {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    clear: left;      
}

input, textarea{
    margin-top: 15px;
}

#submit{
    margin-left: 150px;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

CSS is working fine on textboxes but dropdown boxes are not aligned properly. Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `margin-top: 10px` to `select`:

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/jhvmuwjs/5/)

```
input:not(:last-child), textarea, select {
    width: 200px;
}
select {
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 210px;
}
```

Comment: width should be equal as well

Comment: still the same dropdown and website text box width should be same as other textboxes width

Answer (score 1):

You are not including the "select" element in the style.

This will fix it:

```
input, textarea, select{
margin-top: 15px;}
```

I have edited your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jhvmuwjs/1/).

Answer (score 1):

Just add select in your class

```
input, textarea, select{
    margin-top: 15px;}
```